# Laravel 4.0 Filter and Ajax to load a bootstrap modal pop up

Tags: ajax, laravel-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm doing a website based laravel 4.2 and Bootstrap. I want a bootstrap modal pop up dialog to load on certain routes provided that the user is not already logged in.
So far i have accomplsihed it to load for the entire application upon loading which is not i want but am in the right direction.

This is my ajax call

```
script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() {
 $.get("status", function(data, status){
    data.status == false ? $('#modal-form').modal({backdrop: 'static'}) : $('#modal-form').modal('hide');
});
```

});

Status refers to a URL defined in this route

```
Route::get('/status', 'LoginController@getLoginStatus');
```

and the method is defined here

```
public function getLoginStatus()
{
    return Response::json(array( 'status' => Sentry::check()));
}
```

From that, the modal dialog loads on each route across the entire application. I would want to limit the dialog to load on certain routes provided the user is not logged in.

Thing Laravel filter would do the trick for me but i have failed to do so.
Something like

```
Route::filter('status', function()
{ 
});
```

and then the route be like:

```
Route::get('profile', array('as' => 'submit-profile','before' => 'status','uses' => 'ProfileController@getProfile'));
```

Thanks guys hope you can give me some advice.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the

```
Route::currentRouteName()
```

to check what route your on and then do your preferred action,
like calling the ajax get request for the modal.